# CSS not loading in flask no matter what I do, even if loaded directly into HTML file

Tags: html, css, flask

I have been having this weird CSS error thing where even though flask says the file is being loaded it doesn't show up. I have tried different browsers, changing the file location, rewriting the file links, and even putting the CSS directly into the HTML file. NOTHING.

CSS file:

```
.img_half_and_half_right{
        height: 850px;
        width: 50%;
        animation: fadeOut ease 5s forwards;
        animation-delay: 1s;
        size: relative;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
}
.img_half_and_half_left{
        height: 850px;
        width: 50%;
        animation: fadeOut ease 5s forwards;
        float: left;

}
.thickboi{
        border: solid;
        border-width: 2.5px;
        color: blue;
        border-color: blue;
        padding: 1px;
        margin: 1px;
        float: left;
}

.droptext{
        animation: Dropdowntext ease 5s forwards;
        animation-delay: 7s;
        font-size: 20px;
        opacity:0;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        float: center;
        text-align: center;


.pfpboi{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: turquoise;
        border-radius: 100%;
        margin:10px;
        padding: 1px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        animation: Diaganle_movement ease 3s forwards;
        animation-delay: 6s;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
   0% {
        opacity:1;
        }
  100% {
        opacity:0;
        }
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
        0%{
                opacity:0;
        }
        1%{
                opacity:1;
                }
}
 @keyframes Diaganle_movement{
        0%{
                right: 0px;
                top: 0px;
        }
        100%{
                right: center;
                top: center;
        }
 }

 @keyframes Dropdowntext{
        0%{
                opacity:0;
                top: -1000px;
        }
        100%{
                opacity:1;
                top: -600px;
        }
 }
```

flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, session, flash, request
#from waitress_serve import serves

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/resource')
def resources():
    return render_template('resources.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='192.168.1.56', port='80')
#    serve(app, host='192.168.1.56', port=80)
```

html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <img class='img_half_and_half_right' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/code.jpeg') }}">
        <img class='img_half_and_half_left' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/computerpart.jpg')}}">
        <p class='droptext'>Astoshan Stuerm</p> '
        <center> <div class='pfpboi'></div> </center>
{% endblock %}
```

Please let me know if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since your CSS files are already in the static folder, make this change instead.

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder='static')
```

Comment: That didn't fix it.

Comment: And you should check your static folder path.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page use Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: That did not do anything different.